# every homomorphism from field to ring with more than two elements is an isomorphism

Tags: ring-theory

every homomorphism from field to ring with more than two elements is an isomorphism

how about 
$$
f(x) = 0 
$$

that's not an isomorphism. Should that question say except this case?

Comment: Yes, the zero map is a counterexample that should be mentioned specifically. Keep in mind, though, many authors require ring homomorphisms to preserve the unit element - so $f$ may not satisfy your definition of a homomorphism.

Comment: Some authors define "ring" to mean "ring with $1$," and require that the unit of one ring is mapped to the unit of the other ring. Lang's *Algebra* takes this definition, for example.

Comment: @T.Bongers This is from Joseph Gallian's Abstract Algebra book. He makes a distinction between ring and ring with unity. But I guess in this case it is assumed .

Comment: btw it should read "surjective hom" instead of simply a hom, as stated it is simply false. the point is that the kernel is trivial, and so it is injective. surjectivity does not follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is common practice to assume that rings are rings with identity, and that ring homomorphisms are assumed to take identity elements to identity elements. (This is done in standard textbooks such as the one of Lang, and at any rate in any text on commutative algebra or dealing with commutative algebra.)